# Crystal 2013 - Is field in field possible?

Tags: crystal-reports, report

i am creating a template for an invoice-document. There are some text-blocks i want to include from external via DB-Field so that i can manipulate the text without changing the RPT-File. As some of the Text-Block also inlude VARS i was wondering if there is a chance to also include the VAR itself into the text-block, meaning we have a Field including a Field.

Is this possible? My first tests failed as the Name of the Var is interpreted as text and just printed but not changed into the VAR-Value.

--- Edit ---

Example:

```
Database-Field: {Table1.Value}  -> 4.00
Database-Field: {Table1.Text}   -> 'The value is {Table1.Value}'
```

If i now add {Table1.Text} into the report, it should show as "The value is 4.00"

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. Create a regular text box and set its text. Then drag a database field or a formula from the field explorer on the text box.

Comment: I would only add if you want to format your database fields (as in fonts, style, and sizes), do this before you drag it into the text box. It is a lot harder to edit after it is part of a text box.

Comment: i am not sure if this really answers my questions, so i added an example above. It has nothing to do with formating and even the text from the Textbox should be stored in a DB. I want to move complete Text-Parts our of the report-file.

Comment: This doesn't look like a question for Crystal reports. You are trying to prepare the data so the value in column B to be a result of processing column A. This is something that should be handled during the data retrieval. You can create formulas in your report and to process the data from the columns, but this will be a kind of evaluation engine in each report. Too much work and too much maintenance for nothing.